# How print the exact value which is different while comparing two data frames in R?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, compare

two CSVs are read into two different data frames. on the comparison, there is a requirement that displays the exact value where the difference exists.

I tried with `which` methods on them. it returns some indices which indicate the difference in between the data frames. I tried below code:

`test.data <- fread("file1.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,blank.lines.skip = TRUE)
 truth.data <- fread("file2.csv",stringsAsFactors = DALSE,blank.lines.skip = TRUE)
mismatch <- which(data.frame(test.data) != data.frame(truth.data))
print(mismatch)`

[image: sample truth.data]
[image: sample test.data]

its `which` s output is indices like:

> mismatch > "3"  "4" "8"  " 9"

On accessing the different values of data frames with the help of indices but either it is out bounds of frame or print `NA`.

I also tried `setdiff()` and `anti_join()` methods but they will only show the different values of the first data frame `test.data`.

`print(anti_join(data.frame(test.data), data.frame(truth.data)))`

`print(setdiff(data.frame(test.data), data.frame(truth.data)))`

the required output is like that suppose in some row and certain column in test.data is different than in truth.data. so these both different values should be displayed on the console.

like: As we can see columns two of both samples are different, so i need to show different values of both data frames side by side such that we can easily differentiate between them. number of columns may be varying and more than two rows or columns have different values.

Help me in this. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please add sample data with `dput` or some dummy data we can work with.

Comment: I updated the question, and also mentioned the output. Now help in solving that.